# Apache Beam Windowing stops working and throws Cython error around IntervalWindowBase

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using Beam versions 2.37.0 and 2.43.0, we are reading from streaming source Pub/Sub and using two FixedWindows of 30 minutes to aggregate elements and then group by a key we assigned based on the message. The pipeline works fine for about ~1hr (I can see windows are getting outputed correctly and process afterwards) and then it throws the following error around the IntervalWindowBase:

```
Error message from worker: generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 287, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 360, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 596, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 634, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1003, in process_bundle
    input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 225, in process_encoded
    decoded_value = self.windowed_coder_impl.decode_from_stream(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1465, in decode_from_stream
    value = self._value_coder.decode_from_stream(in_stream, nested)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1008, in decode_from_stream
    return self._construct_from_components([
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1009, in <listcomp>
    c.decode_from_stream(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1194, in decode_from_stream
    elements = [
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1195, in <listcomp>
    self._elem_coder.decode_from_stream(in_stream, True)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1557, in decode_from_stream
    return self._value_coder.decode(in_stream.read(value_length))
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 240, in decode
    return self.decode_from_stream(create_InputStream(encoded), False)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 583, in decode_from_stream
    return self.fallback_coder_impl.decode_from_stream(stream, nested)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 273, in decode_from_stream
    return self._decoder(stream.read_all(nested))
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '__pyx_unpickle__IntervalWindowBase' on <module 'apache_beam.utils.windowed_value' from '/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/windowed_value.py'>

generic::unknown: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 287, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 360, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 596, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 634, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1003, in process_bundle
    input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
  File "/pipeline/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 225, in process_encoded
    decoded_value = self.windowed_coder_impl.decode_from_stream(
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1446, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1465, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.WindowedValueCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1009, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.AbstractComponentCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1195, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.SequenceCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1557, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.LengthPrefixCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 240, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.StreamCoderImpl.decode
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 583, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.FastPrimitivesCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 273, in apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.CallbackCoderImpl.decode_from_stream
  File "stringsource", line 17, in apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase.__setstate_cython__
TypeError: Expected tuple, got dict
```

We are using Dataflow as the Runner. Input type to the windowing is

```
Tuple[str, Dict[str, str]]
```

We have tried decreasing the window size and the issue still happens. Also tried some more strict input/output typing. The windowing seems to work fine for some time and then it suddenly errors out.

Comment: `File "stringsource", line 17, in apache_beam.utils.windowed_value._IntervalWindowBase.__setstate_cython__`: is stringsource your own code? Most likely, the input data from pub/sub causes some issues.

Comment: No all files in these stack trace are internals to the beam library unfortunately

Comment: That stringsource is generated by cython indeed. So from the stack trace, all I can tell is that somehone your input data might be wrong. I am wondering whether you could use the schema for pub/sub (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas) to reveal any potential data issue.